# Learning process automation starting from general engineering background

Tags: laplace-transform, automation, process

I'd like to study process automation by myself, could you suggest a good entry-level book to start with?

I have engineering college math level and I remember a bit of Laplace transforms to model systems. I have successfully implemented many simple PID and fuzzy logic control with microcontrollers, like tank-level control, pH and more.

My goal are to model systems, test automation strategies in Simulink (instead of time-domain simulations like I did until now), and be able to solve multivariate/interactive situations through decoupling (RGA etc.)

Any suggestion would be very appreciated!

Best,

Comment: What type of process do you mean? Electronic? Mechanical? Chemical? Factory production lines?

Comment: Also, ain't Simulink pretty much time-domain simulation? Whether it is discrete or an approximation of the continuous modeled system.

Comment: @jDAQ I used other tool than Simulink to make time domain simulation (check goldsim). Using Simulink or Labview is standard in process automation with pre-programmed blocks

Yes, physical (mostly tank level), chemical processes (pH, other reactions). Today my issue is really to deal with interactive systems and I find that I am not comfortable with the basics when it comes to read about RGA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an entry-level book I can recommend [Modern Control Engineering](https://www.pearson.com/store/p/modern-control-engineering/P100000002067) from Ogata. It teaches system modelling and control theory, just what you're looking for.

Also, take a look at [Scilab](https://www.scilab.org/)  and [Xcos](https://www.scilab.org/software/xcos), which are open-source alternatives to Matlab and Simulink respectively. Since these are open source, there is a lot of free information for these platforms on process automation.

Comment: From the "...be able to solve multivariate/interactive situations through decoupling (RGA etc.)" part I supposed he knew the basics of control and was looking for something more specific, specially related to huge systems in which that decoupling could help optimize separately each process.

Comment: I managed to implement PID without doing any Laplace Transform, just using differential equations and time-based calculations. In most case, I ended doing online tuning using Ziegler Nichols criteria.
Preface says "The reader is expected to have fulfilled the following
prerequisites: introductory courses on differential equations, Laplace transforms, vector-matrix analysis, circuit analysis, mechanics, and introductory thermodynamics."

Comment: Oh well, then you are in for a big trip discovering state-space methods.

Comment: Also, did you mean you implemented a PID algorithm one time or had a whole class on controls and never used a Laplace transform? Anyway, for linear time-invariant SISO systems the approach should be very similar, but for MIMO and non-LTI only the time-domain approach works.

Comment: @jDAQ I never had a class. I did implement level control, pH control and some other physical/chemical control at industrial scale, in very practical approach. MIMO gives me problems (let's say controlling levels in a serie of connected tanks), that's why I'd like to learn decoupling theory/application. What is LTI?

Comment: linear time-invariant (LTI)

Comment: @javier-acuna Thank you, seems I have most of prerequisites after reading the preface. Also, it’s a 1000 pages book, that will take some time!

Comment: I'm glad that I could be of help :). Don't get discouraged by the length of the book, there is waaay more material than one normal introductory lecture to control systems. Depending on background, you might skip the first chapters. For process automation is "Chapter 8 PID Controllers" the most important IMHO. Cheers!